# c# uwp virtualization issue

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, virtualization

I have a grid view that is populated with lot of items...each item has a Image in it. And when user scrolls down, some items become unrealized by virtualization. And, when user scrolls back to show them, those items start to update data, image source. The problem is that updating image source blocks the UI, and items in my grid are not showing until the image is loaded. This looks bad, and very choppy scrolling...

Here is the example what virtualization is doing in gridview:

[image]

My question is, how to set number of items that virtualization will make realized?

Comment: the virtualization is handled by the `GridView` control which is not open source so we don't know exactly how it is done. You can try playing with the `ItemsPanel` of the `GridView` Which by default is an [`ItemsWrapGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid) and see if there is something to help you there. However, there is another way to achieve smooth scrolling while the images are being loaded. You can use [`x:Phase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-phase-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CacheLength` property of the virtualizing panel.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel CacheLength="0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

If cache length is in multiples of view port size. So if 3 items are visible in the window and cache length is 1, then you'll have 3 realized items before and 3 realized items after, (3+3+3 = 9). If cache length is 2, then 6+6+3 = 15, etc.

This works with `GridView` as well:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid CacheLength="0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```